# Laravel resource::all with values from another table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm learning Laravel right now and i have following tables and resources (models, controllers, ect.):

```
tickets
- id
- title
- projectID
- statusID

projects
- id
- title

status
- id
- title
```

I have to make a list of my Tickets on the Startpage. Not nessesary to say that i need the Project- and Statustiltles and not the IDs. Currently i do:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $tickets = Ticket::all();
    return View::make('layout')->with('tickets', $tickets);
});
```

My current output is:

```
tickets->id, tickets->title, tickets->projectID, tickets->statusID
```

The output i want is

```
tickets->id, tickets->title, tickets->projects->title, tickets->status->title
```

So i hope anyone can understand what i'm trying to ask here and maybe provide me some help. Thank you!

---

**Resolution**: I had to set the foreign_keys first in my DB. Then i used the relationships mentioned in the answers and it works fine.

My Model:

```
class Ticket extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Project', 'id', 'projectID');
    }

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Status', 'id', 'statusID');
    }
}
```

My View:

```
@foreach($tickets as $key => $value)
...
  <td>{{ $value->project->title }}</td>
  <td>{{ $value->status->title }}</td>
...
@endforeach
```

Comment: What you need is "relationships" - http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you configure you **relationships** correctly you can do that without problems using the **Laravel Eager Loading** feature, for example:

---

> ### Eager Loading ([Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading))
>
> Eager loading exists to alleviate the N + 1 query problem...

```
class Ticket extends Eloquent {

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Project', 'projectID', 'id');
    }

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Status', 'statusID', 'id');
    }

}
```

Now, just call the fields you want, for example:

```
foreach (Ticket::all() as $ticket)
{
    echo $ticket->project->title;
    echo $ticket->status->title;
}
```

---

**Obs.:** In your return object/array you can't see the relationships fields unless you do manual joins, etc. So, just configure your relationships and call the fields you want.

*Sorry for my english*

Comment: @Bandicood This will not work with your custom FKs and will cause n+1 issue

Comment: Add eager loading, otherwise it's overkill

Comment: @deczo Yes I know that. Because that I write in end "manual joins". Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Not really, all you need is to use `with`.

Comment: @deczo About that, I don't know "what is better". But thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

Define relationships specifying custom foreign keys (defaults would be `status_id` and `project_id` for your models):

```
// Ticket model
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Project', 'projectID');
}

public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Status', 'statusID');
}
```

Then eager load related models:

```
$tickets = Ticket::with('project','status')->get();

// accessing:
foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
{
   $ticket->status; // Status model with all its properties
   $ticket->project; // Project model
}
```